# Imshow and imwrite showing blank image in matlab

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to store images in an array for some analysis. When I loop the process and 'imwrite' the result into various files, it stores a blank image (same for 'imshow' ).
When I print the image array on console, the values are what should they be (varying from 50 to 200). Here's my part of code which goes wrong. Please help:

**Necessary variaables have been initialised before the loop. image is non-blank. reduced image is the array which shows non zero on printing 'reduced_image(:,:,k);' but shows blank image in inshow. Same for 'Img' variable. I have tried removing the squeeze function an use loopwise copying of pixel's, but that gave the same result **

```
for k=1:level
    for i=1:H/(2^k)
        for j=1:W/(2^k)
            reduced_image(i,j,k) = uint8 (( uint32(Image_current(2*i,2*j)) + uint32(Image_current(2*i - 1 ,2*j - 1)) )/2 ) ; 
        end
    end
    Img =  squeeze(reduced_image(:,:,k)) ;
    imwrite( Img , 'output.jpg' ) ;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime, It because imshow try to use a range.

Just try :

```
imshow(Img,[]);
```

That force `imshow` to use the current range image without rescale it.

Or maybe you can just do

```
imshow(Img,[50 200]);
```

But that will rescale your image to be between 0 and 255 (Just on the display, the array isn't modified).

**EDIT**

To capture your display image you can do :

```
h = figure;
imshow(Img,[]);

saveas(h,'PathImage.jpg');
```

**EDIT 2**

Normalize between 0 - 1 and multiply by 255 to get 0 to 255 image. Double cast is for the division and uint8 is to get back into image format.

```
maxVal = max(Img(:));
minVal = min(Img(:));

Img = uint8(255*double(double(Img(:) - minVal) / double( maxVal - minVal))));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you just tell me how do I use imwrite this way correctly?

Comment: When you imwrite, it keep the data on the workspace format. You want to save the display you have with the imshow ?

Comment: Yes. I do. But I dont want to show the image in the final code, I was just showing it for testing. Is there any way to o it without imshow?

Comment: Sorry but I think that still requires the imshow. Whereas, I want to do it without inshow.

Comment: Normalize the image. Look Edit 2. If it not want you want, I don't really know what to do right now sorry.

Comment: Edit 2 helped. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with data format conversions. This version works:

```
for k=1:level
    for i=1:H/(2^k)
        for j=1:W/(2^k)
            reduced_image(i,j,k) = (double(Image_current(2*i,2*j)) + double(Image_current(2*i - 1 ,2*j - 1)) )/2 ; 
        end
    end
    Img =  squeeze(reduced_image(:,:,k)) ;
    imwrite(uint8(Img) , [int2str(k), 'output.jpg']) ;
end
```

Comment: Well I tried this. Does not work for me, output is blank: same as before. :(

Comment: Could you provide example of image? It works for me for grayscale images.

Comment: Yes. I am using grayscale images only. I am updating the whole code  in the question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

The following line of code maybe missing....check it out

tagstruct.RowsPerStrip = 16

So maybe missing RowsPerStrip field of tagstruct is the cause of the image of all zeros.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Matlab. Where am I supposed to put this line?