# 2D convolution in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, convolution

```
I = imread ("lena.jpg");
%imshow(I);
K = I;
C = conv2(I, K);
imshow(C);
```

I am expecting something like the following as indicated in [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38709810/159072).

[image]

But, my octave output is blank:

[image]

**What could be the possible reason?**

And, how can I obtain the expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imshow and imwrite showing blank image in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978924/imshow-and-imwrite-showing-blank-image-in-matlab)

Comment: Hum... maybe this one is better as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985585/why-am-i-getting-a-blank-image-as-my-output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imshow()` expect values between [0-255]. After your convolution all your value are way above 255. So of course when you use `imshow(C)`,  matlab/octave do a type conversion using `uint8()`. All your value equal 255 and the result is a white image. (0 = black, 255 = white).

You also should take into account severals things:

1. add the option 'same' to your convolution to preserve the original size of your image: `conv2(I,K,'same')`
2. If you only apply the convolution like that, you will obtain a strong border effect, because the central values of your image will be multiplied more time than the values in the border of your image. You should add a compensation matrix:

   `border_compensation = conv2(ones(size(K)),ones(size(K)),'same')
   C = conv2(I,K,'same')./border_compensation`
3. Normalize the final result (Don't take into account the point 2. if you really want the kind of output that you pointed out in your question)

   `C = uint8(C/max(C(:))*255)`